# Multiple planar reflections works weird in UE4

Tags: architecture, rendering, unreal-4

When I add multiple planar reflections for arch-viz, some of them on glasses don't have any result, but ones on mirror works properly.

Sometimes all the planar reflections on glass are invalid. But after restart the engine, the reflections get back to normal.

Any clue to fix it? Or it is the Engine limit.

(No ray tracing.)

Below are my material settings.

Glass material:
[image]

Mirror material:
[image]

Comment: Maybe show how the planar reflections look...

Comment: @Raildex . Looks like the glass material preview sphere in the picture. Reflect nothing at all.

Comment: but thats not a planar reflection.

Comment: Exactly, no planar reflection on **translucent blend mode** material(like glass). In the mean while the **opaque blend mode** material(like mirror or any other glossy material) works properly as expected.